# jQuery custom plugin: returning a value to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've used jQuery for a few years and love it. However, I have a lot of functions in my project that I would like to make as an extended jQuery function.

For this example, I will use the $.post function to demonstrate when I am trying to accomplish with my own function:

```
$.post('file.php', { arg1: 'hi', arg2: 'hi2' }, function ( data ) {
    // Is called after function completes
    // and returns a value (in this case data)
});
```

What I think the function would look

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.popup = function( options ) {

    options = $.extend( $.fn.popup.defaults, options );

    if ( options.type === 1 ) 
        var opt = '<table><tr><td><div id="pConfirm">CONFIRM</div></td><td><div id="pCancel">CANCEL</div></td></tr></table>';

    $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay-control"></div>');
    $('body').prepend('<div class="info-overlay"><h1>'+title+'</h1>'+ message + opt +'</div>');

    $(document).on('click', 'pConfirm', function () {
        //callback would happen here and would return a value
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'pCancel', function () {
        //callback would happen here and would return a value
    });
});
```

How it would be called

```
$.popup('title', 'message', 'type', function(ret) {
    if ( ret === 0 )
        //Cancelled
    else
        //Accepted
}
```

I am hoping someone could post an example that would support a few values and be able to return a result or point me towards a good tutorial.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you just asking how you call the callback function from your function? Or something more complicated? In the latter case, it depends on what your plugin does. For instance, `$.post` runs the callback function in the XMLHttpRequest `onreadystatechange` event handler.

Comment: @Barmar In this scenario, .popup would be replacing alert(). It's simple... After $.popup() is executed, it should wait for the OK or CONFIRM button to be clicked and then does a callback to the function.  I'll make a quick edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that allows you to pass in options and a callback. The callback is executed when one of the buttons is clicked, and it receives the type of button e.g. `CONFIRM` or `CANCEL`.

You'll notice that I don't use element ID's or classes to get a handle on them. Instead, it keeps a reference to the elements after creating. The benefit of this is that it makes it more generic and won't run into class or ID conflicts with other code.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dn67u/1/)

Plugin code:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        popup: function(options, callback) {
            var container;

            function actionClicked(){
                var type = $(this).data('type');
                container.remove(); // remove the popup from the DOM
                callback(type); // execute callback
            }

            // create buttons under a table
            var table = $('<table><tr><td class="confirm"></td><td class="cancel"></td></tr></table>');

            table.find('.confirm').append(
                $('<button></button>', { type : 'button' })
                    .data('type', 'CONFIRM')
                    .text('Confirm')
                    .click(actionClicked)
            );

            table.find('.cancel').append(
                $('<button></button>', { type : 'button' })
                    .data('type', 'CANCEL')
                    .text('Cancel')
                    .click(actionClicked)
            );


            // create the popup elements
            container = $('<div class="info-overlay"></div>')
                .append(
                    $('<h1></h1>').text(options.title)
                )
                .append(
                    $('<p></p>').text(options.message)
                )
                .append(table);

            $('body').prepend(container);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$.popup({ title : 'my title', message : 'my message', type : 'my type' }, function(action){
    console.log("selected action " + action);

    if(action == 'CONFIRM'){
        // confirmed
    } else if(action == 'CANCELLED') {
        // cancelled
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for and some. I will try this out and post back shortly.

Comment: Okay, so I've had a chance to mess around with it... To be honest, I've never seen a robust way of appending elements to the DOM before... How would I wrap up the buttons within a DIV so I can isolate the buttons from the rest of the elements?

Comment: The buttons are wrapped by `<div class="info-overlay">`. See that it creates this div called `container` and appends the buttons to it.

Comment: I see that, however so are the other elements. If you notice, the original example uses a <table> so that the buttons are spaced out equally (in the rare event I will use 3 buttons opposed to 1) and are isolated away from the <h1> and the <p>. In other words, I want buttons to be nested into another div BUT, they remain inside the overlay container.

Comment: Eg: `<div id="info-overlay"><h1>Header</h1><p>Message</p><table><tr><td><button>Button1</button></td><td><button>Button2</td></tr></table></div>`

Comment: See my edit, that should do it. There are many ways of doing it, this is just one.

Answer (score 0):

excuse me if I am offbase here.

perhaps something like:

short example:

```
$(document).bind('pConfirm', function (event, obj) {
    //callback would happen here and would return a value
    console.log(obj.tester) // testing
});

$(document).bind('pCancel', function () {
    //callback would happen here and would return a value
});
```

then in your $.popup instantiation.

```
 jQuery( document.body ).trigger( "pConfirm", { tester: 'it works!' } );
```

something tells me I might be offbase in terms of your needs, but worth a shot.